# Need to delete a junk file created while running a shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a shell script `test.sh`.

Within that I am trying to execute another shell script `abc.sh`.
When `abc.sh` is executed it takes in one of the options a,b,c.
If I choose "a " and press <kbd>enter</kbd>, it creates a temp file and opens it and if I give "q" it quits from the screen and deletes the temp file.

But when I call `test.sh`, it calls `abc.sh` and the temp file is opened.

I want to copy the temp file to home dir created by `abc.sh`, press <kbd>q</kbd> so that it exits from the script and continues with `test.sh`.

The constraint is I am not allowed to modify abc.sh.

abc.sh has the logic to create the temp file and on completion i.e if I hit the "q" key and it exits out of the script it deletes the temp file as well.

With the help from the folks here, I am now able to copy the contents to the home dir using the command :

```
touch /tmp/reference_file; { echo a; sleep 1; find /tmp -newer /tmp/reference_file -exec cp "{}" ~ \; 2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2); echo q; } | ./abc.sh; rm /tmp/reference_file;
```

But this command is creating a junk file as follows in the place where I am executing test.sh:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxx xxxxx 310 Aug 20 11:04 ▒
```

Can someone help me on how to delete it? or if anything is wrong with my command above?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a very satisfactory solution - what happens if some other program / process happens to create a file in `/tmp` in the meantime? If `abc.sh` uses `mktemp`, then it may be sufficient to set the `TMPDIR` directory before calling it e.g. `printf 'a\nq\n' | TMPDIR=$HOME ./abc.sh`

Comment: Are you simply asking for a way to test for the existence of the tempfile in a known location? Or are you asking for a way to assuredly delete the tempfile that is already known to exist? It's hard to tell from your question.